# How do I debug a REST request when I can't see the output of "dump()" calls?

Tags: php, symfony, cors, symfony4

I want to debug the Request sent to my Controller method :

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class IteropController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/api/getiterop", name="api_get_iterop")
     * @Rest\RequestParam(name="sary", nullable=true)
     */
    public function getIteropForm(Request $req)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setContent(json_encode(['prenom' => $req->request->get('prenom') , 'sary' => $req->files->get('sary') ? 'misy' : 'tsisy']));
        dump($req->getContent());
        return $response;
    }
}
```

But at runtime I get `(failed)net::ERR_FAILED` in the Network tab of the browser development tool, and the CORS error appears on the console log of the browser.

So how to debug the Rest POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to debug PHP, usually the best thing is to install and learn to use Xdebug (nothing beats a real step-by-step debugger).

Or you install the Symfony Profiler (`require profiler-pack`) and the `symfony/debug-bundle` (`require symfony/debug-bundle`), which allows you to see the output of `dump()` calls in the profiler output (you would look for the `X-Debug-Token-Link` header in the response headers, which include a link to the profiler record, and the output for `dump()` is on the "Debug" tab).

---

Nevertheless, for CORS problems a PHP debugger will only tell you so much. The Symfony profiler might be more useful, since it can tell you more information about the request. But what you really need to do is to inspect the response headers to see if you are getting all the CORS headers you expect.

Also, on certain scenarios browsers will send pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests to verify CORS headers, and if you do not account correctly for those, the browser request might fail as well. Or if you are using credentials in the request, using `*` as origin is simply not allowed. So the first step for debugging is to check those requests and the corresponding response headers.